# How to retrieve the lambda caller identity ( lambda ARN, IAM Role,... ) on a lambda to lambda communication

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, aws-lambda, identity-management

I have a scenario with Lambdas ( many/caller ) to Lambda (one) communication using AWS Invoke() API call where I need to identify the caller Lambda.

Which information could be used to get the lambda caller ?
I cannot rely on the event data as for invoke() API the event content is fully controlled by the caller and I need to get the identity information from another place ( context ? )

Thanks.

Comment: How is one Lambda function invoking the other Lambda function? It could simply pass some identifying information with the `Invoke()` request.

Comment: The caller should not put any information in the event to identify himself as it is not trusted.  I would like to rely on trusted information from the context if any like the IAM Role of the caller or its ARN.

Comment: Are you saying that you do not control the initial "Lambdas (many)"? Are these coming from other people? If so, then your "Lambda (one)" is effectively receiving API calls. How are the "many" Lambdas invoking the "one" Lambda? Is it via API Gateway, via an AWS Invoke() API call, or via Lambda Function URL? Also, what do you mean by "identify the caller" -- what 'identity' are you wanting to obtain? Please add these additional details to your Question.

Comment: Updated. Mainly Invoke API at first.  And I need to see if there is a way to get the IAM roles or whatever information of the caller to identify clearly who is calling the lambda.
I need to identify the caller as there is a need to give back some contextuel information depending of the lambda that invoke the API ( caller )

Comment: So you are saying that the "many" Lambda call `Invoke()` to trigger your "one" Lambda? That means these callers would be using AWS credentials to invoke your Lambda function, is that correct? That is a very strange way to get third-parties to call your Lambda function. What sort of "identity" are you wanting to obtain?

Comment: IAM Role of the caller lambda

Comment: The [AWS Lambda context object](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-context.html) does not seem to provide that information.

Comment: Ok thanks. I will then go though an internal API Gateway to will propagate some identity information to the lambda.

Answer (score 2):

You would need to use [event](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/gettingstarted-concepts.html#gettingstarted-concepts-event) information

according to [Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-handler.html)

> The event object contains information from the invoking service. When you invoke a function, you determine the structure and contents of the event. When an AWS service invokes your function, the service defines the event structure.

Side Note: If you want to coordinate lambda worklflow using [step functions](https://aws.amazon.com/step-functions/features/) would be a better choice.